# Repeating-image header and full page background image with CSS [code included]

Tags: css, header, banner

My web page uses a full page stretch background image. My problem is that the background image seems to be covering the top 10px banner/header I am trying to add in the form of a repeating background image (so I can use CSS opacity). Here's the full page:

```
<html><head>
<style type="text/css" media=screen>

body{
    margin: 0px;
    color: #000;
    font-family: helvetica, times;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 

  /* Preserve aspet ratio */
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#banner{
  background: url('images/banner2.gif');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding:50px;
  text-align: center;
}

</style></head>

<body>

<img src="images/background.jpg" id="bg">

<div id="banner">
Banner Test Text
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried adding z-index but to no solution. Any input for what I'm doing wrong is hugely appreciated. Please note that this implementation of the full page background image is the best I have achieved with my image, so it'd be great if a solution to accommodate that.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, managed to get it myself. For any future readers of this, all I needed to do was add

```
position:absolute;
```

To the #banner code.